# Perform sql join using sqlcontext spark

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark

I tried running a query for querying Oracle db with joins using sqlcontext like,

```
val sql="select a from b,c where b.join=c.join"
val dataframe = sqlcontext.read.jdbc(url,sql,connection_properties)
```

I am getting invalid tablename error. 
However if I try querying table like below it works fine.

```
val df1 = sqlcontext.read.jdbc(url,"b",connection_properties)
val df2 = sqlcontext.read.jdbc(url,"c",connection_properties)
```

Will it not be possible to run join queries using sqlcontext.

Answer (score 2):

This is what you need to do, create two dataframes from the tables as below

```
val df1 = sqlcontext.read.jdbc(url,"b",connection_properties)
val df2 = sqlcontext.read.jdbc(url,"c",connection_properties)
```

and join two dataframes with the key you want to join

```
df1.join(df2, <join condition>, <which join>)

//example
df1.join(df2, df1($"id") === df2($"id"), "left")
```

I think this is a better option as far I know

Hope this helps!